# If I add new possible values to my enum type, will this change my wsdl?

Tags: c#, web-services, enums, wsdl

I have a web service and I'm using an enum type in it. I have made some changes in my code and i added a new value to my enum type. Is this going to change my wsdl declaration ? And is that going to break all the clients that use my web service ? I use .NET

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will change your WSDL.

However, it won't "break" your clients, in all likelihood.

OTOH, if you don't want clients to see the new enum value, then you should not include it: create two enum types: one to be used internally, and one to be returned from the web service. Convert from one to the other.

Comment: It's ok for my clients to see the new value. I just don't want to force them to update their service references, if they don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it changes your wsdl, but in a non-breaking way as long as the new enum value is added to the end of the enum. Newer clients won't be able to submit that enum unless they update their service references.